# how to get the object from the attribute value of the element selected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am generating the list from the javascript and trying to get the object from the clicked list item .

```
 options=[
 {
label: "Contact",
message: "Contact Not Found",
"tab": "contact",
"subTabTitle" : "ContactName",
"subTabId" : "contactTab",
"tabContentId" : "contactData",
"svc" : `${config.getContactSvc()}`
}

,
{
"label": "Account",
"message": "Account Not Found",
"tab": "account",
"subTabTitle" : "AccountNumber",
"subTabId" : "accountTab",
"tabContentId" : "accountData",
"svc" :`${config.getAccountSvc()}`

},

{
"label": "Asset",
"message": "Asset Not Found",
"tab": "assets",
"subTabTitle" : "SecurityTypeDescription",
"subTabId" : "assetTab",
"tabContentId" : "assetData",
"svc" : `${config.getAccountAssetSvc()}`


 },
 ]
```

---

```
 var $dropdownSearch = $("#dropdownMenu")
for (var obj of options) {
var $menuItem = $(`<li><a class="newanchor" href="#" id= ${obj.label} 
 type="submit">Search ${obj.tab}</a></li>`)
$menuItem.click(() => {     
  //todo
   var promise= search(obj)

})
$dropdownSearch.append($menuItem)
 }
```

When I click on the any element of the list I always end up getting the last elements object .how do I get the selected list elements object

Comment: Since you use an arrow function, you can use `let` instead of `var` to keep the correct obj reference. Else you'd have to `bind()` the correct value to a normal function, or search the options array again by id.

Comment: Thanks just the change of var to  let did the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using let instead of var.

```
let $dropdownSearch = $("#dropdownMenu")
for (let obj of options) {
let $menuItem = $(`<li><a class="newanchor" href="#" id= ${obj.label} 
 type="submit">Search ${obj.tab}</a></li>`)
$menuItem.click(() => {     
  //todo
   let promise= search(obj)

})
$dropdownSearch.append($menuItem)
 }
```